# Pulling Frequent JSON Data from API with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to make Meteor monitor a sports-data JSON feed in real-time.  I know how to use the HTTP package to make the call and parse the response on the Meteor server, but I'm curious how best to stay up to date with [the feed](http://live.nhle.com/GameData/GCScoreboard/2013-02-01.jsonp).

Should I set a loop that pulls and parses the feed at regular intervals?  Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: How often is frequent?

Comment: Good question -- seconds are not critical, but a minute delay is too much.  I'm thinking I will use a really short-interval cronjob or roll a separate service that dumps into Meteor's Mongo instance.

Comment: I would also recommend the solution posted by @FullStack if the data really truly needs to be in sync with the remote data at all times. If it only needs to appear that way to a client, then perhaps you could instead do it at regular (<  1 minute) intervals by the server (Meteor.isServer) when clients are connected and longer intervals when no client is connected to avoid having to pull in data often when no one is around to use it.

Comment: Awesome -- thank you @GPicazo and FullStack!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should schedule cron jobs every 5 minutes or something like that. Check out [this great package](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) for scheduling cron jobs in Meteor. Below is an example. It's as simple as calling a function.

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 2 hours');
  },
  job: function() {
    var numbersCrunched = CrushSomeNumbers();
    return numbersCrunched;
  }
});
```

Comment: SyncedCron is the bomb.